# (UPDATED) Published blazor wasm app fails to connect to Postgresql

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, .net-core, blazor, npgsql

Update 2: this solved the issue for me: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host

Also had to make sure I added an https address in the Urls entry in appsettings.json

---

Update: if checked Postgres logs and found this:

```
2022-05-09 21:57:59.816 PKT [11284] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "safzal"
2022-05-09 21:57:59.816 PKT [11284] DETAIL:  Role "safzal" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 89: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256"
```

"safzal" is my PC username but not the username I configured in connection string. Why isn't dotnet using my connection string?

---

I am making a Blazor wasm (hosted) app with Postgres db. During development, I put connection string without mentioning userid or password in appSettings.json. I used user secrets to store userid and password and linked them in Program.cs. This approach worked fine, I was able to use `dotnet ef migrations add myMigration` and `dotnet ef database update`. I was able to use the app normally during development.

However, when I publish, I cannot get the db connection to work. The app loads fine but as soon as I attempt data access it shows "An unhandled error has occured." with option to Reload.

I get the following http 500 internal server error error in browser console:
[image: 500 Internal Server Error]

I was initially using IIS to attempt to run the app. When I tried to run it via Kestrel it shows this error:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'fistepsdb' on server ''.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'fisteps.Server.Data.AppDbContext'.
      Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): No password has been provided but the backend requires one (in SASL/SCRAM-SHA-256)
```

I have already tried:

- Putting userId and password directly in connection string
- Putting connection string in VS2022 Publish dialog > Show all settings > Settings > Databases > [Password, PostgreSqlConnection, UserId]
- Putting connection string in IIS > Sites > Default Web Site > Management > Configuration Editor > Section: connectionStrings (though I am unsure about providerName here).

Any help would be most appreciated.